# Checksum Failure

Tags: php, checksum

I've got this script and it produces the following error: 001 Checksum failure

This is the script, I don't know what's wrong with it, could you help me?

```
<?php 

/*  

  Access control for TargetPay Pay per Use  
  (C) TargetMedia 2007 

  Upload this file in the protected directory and make sure  
  that .htaccess support is enabled. 

  MODIFICATIONS IN THIS CODE ARE ALLOWED BUT NOT SUPPORTED 

  Product-ID: 28717    Generated: 16-01-2011 14:57:05 

*/ 

define ("CHECKSUM", "739b54dc26"); 
define ("ERR001", "001 Checksum failure"); 
define ("ERR002", "002 Can't open .htaccess for writing. Check rights."); 
define ("ERR003", "003 I/O Error, cannot write to .htaccess. Disk full?");

list($thispage) = explode("?", 
    "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 

$payscreen = "http://www.targetpay.nl/send/?id=28717&rtlo=51090". 
    "&pm=".urlencode("inline=1"). 
    "&ref=".urlencode($thispage); 

header ("Content-type: text/plain"); 

if ($_GET["checksum"] != CHECKSUM) { 
    die (ERR001); 
    } 

function ip2hex ($ip) { 
    list ($a,$b,$c,$d) = explode(".", $ip); 
    return    str_pad(dechex($a),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT). 
            str_pad(dechex($b),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT). 
            str_pad(dechex($c),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT). 
            str_pad(dechex($d),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    } 

function hex2ip ($hex) { 
    return  hexdec(substr($hex,0,2)).".". 
            hexdec(substr($hex,2,2)).".". 
            hexdec(substr($hex,4,2)).".". 
            hexdec(substr($hex,6,2)); 
    } 

function parse ($whitelist, $payscreen) { 
    $here = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], 
        strrpos ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "/") + 1); 

    $o =    "ErrorDocument 403 $payscreen\n". 
            "<Files .htaccess>\n". 
            "Order allow,deny\n". 
            "Deny from all\n". 
            "</Files>\n". 
            "<Files $here>\n". 
            "Order allow,deny\n". 
            "Allow from all\n". 
            "</Files>\n". 
            "Order deny,allow\n". 
            "Deny from all\n"; 

    if ((!$whitelist) || ($whitelist=="empty")) { 
        return $o; } 

    $iplist = explode(",", $whitelist); 
    foreach ($iplist as $hex) { 
        $ip = hex2ip ($hex); 
        if ($ip) { 
            $o .= "Allow from $ip\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    return $o; 
    } 

if ($_GET["register"]) { 
    $fp = @fopen(".htaccess", "w+"); 
    if (!$fp) { 
        die (ERR002); 
        } 
    if (!@fwrite ($fp, parse($_GET["register"],$payscreen))) { 
        die (ERR003); 
        } 
    @fclose ($fp); 
    echo "000 OK"; 
    } 

if ($_GET["reset"]) { 
    @unlink (".htaccess"); 
    $fp = @fopen(".htaccess", "w+"); 
    if (!$fp) { 
        die (ERR002); 
        } 
    if (!@fwrite ($fp, parse("",$payscreen))) { 
        die (ERR003); 
        } 
    @fclose ($fp); 
    echo "000 RESET OK"; 
    } 

if ($_GET["dump"]) { 
    echo @implode("",file(".htaccess")); 
    echo "\n-EOF-"; 
    } 
?>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What does `$_GET["checksum"]` contain and why does it differ from `739b54dc26`? That is something only you (or maybe Targetpay's support) can answer. It is not a programming problem as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think its an error. actually

```
if($_GET["checksum"] != CHECKSUM) { 
    die (ERR001);
}
```

this condition is getting true, so the output not error.
so just check the GET data from wherever you are getting it initially.Its not a programmatic error for sure.

Comment: So i need to remove the ! ? Let's try and see.

Comment: DONT REMOVE it as it is.It must have been there for some purpose. Find out that and find what $GET are you supplying to your script.I hope you know. http://localhost/test.php?checksum=739b54dc26 and this script will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke the script via GET with, at least, this parameter:

```
checksum=739b54dc26
```

so if your page is test.php, on localhost, call it this way (you may add other parameters to the request string of course):

```
http://localhost/test.php?checksum=739b54dc26
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Well the problem is , is that this script is used for micropayments. So i don't know what value they are sending back to me. I used ; echo $_GET['checksum']; but that did not echo the checksum value for me..

Comment: @Andre Woons do you mean that the checksum value in $_GET was empty?

Comment: I guess, if it displays nothing it's empty right?

Comment: yes.. the problem then is in the way the script is being invoked, not in the script itself. In order to run, the script needs to be invoked with the "checksum" value equal to "739b54dc26"

Comment: So that's a fail from the payment service provider then, they are basicilly returning the wrong checksum value? Or am i wrong?

Comment: If the payment service provider is invoking this script on your side and they are not sending to you the "checksum" parameter with the value "739b54dc26" then there are only two possibilities: they are invoking the script in a incorrect way or the checksum parameter is no longer used (or must have a different value) in the communication protocol between you and them.